# Separating images with shutil copy problem

Tags: python

I have a file name massPictures=[] that contains a list of .png file names. I have a .csv that I used to filter the pictures based off a criteria.

I am using shutil.copy to go through a directory with images and select the ones on massPicture and move them to a folder then take the ones that are not on that list and move them into a different folder.

```
import os
import shutil

for filenamewithmass in massPictures:
    for filename in os.listdir('Chest Xrays'):
        filenametry = 'Chest Xrays/'+filename
        if(filenamewithmass == filename):
            shutil.copy(filenametry,'Mass',follow_symlinks = True)
        else:
            shutil.copy(filenametry, 'NoMass',follow_symlinks = True)
```

The problem though is the else statement does not seem to be working and files that go into the folder Mass are also being sent to the folder NoMass.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through the list of the files and then through the files itself. Obviously, for every file, there will be a case when it matches something from the list, and there will be a case when it does not. You should iterate through files, and compare them to the list, then make a proper copy only once (not num(files) * num(list), like you do now):

```
for filename in os.listdir('Chest Xrays'):
    filenametry = 'Chest Xrays/'+filename
    if(filename in massPictures):
        shutil.copy(filenametry,'Mass',follow_symlinks = True)
    else:
        shutil.copy(filenametry, 'NoMass',follow_symlinks = True)
```